# Why doesn't NodeJS execute constructors the way browsers do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, constructor

I was playing around with NodeJS and I noticed something strange.

I was just exploring the use of constructors through the code below.

```js
// We declare the constructor.
function Personne(inName) {
    console.log("go!");
    if ('undefined' != typeof inName) {
        this.name = inName;
    }
}

// We declare the object's prototype (that will be used by the constructor).
var PersonnePrototype = {
    name: 'toto',
    setName: function(inName) {
        this.name = inName; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
    },
    getName: function() {
        return this.name; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
    }
};

Personne.prototype = PersonnePrototype;

var p = new Personne("Tom"); 
console.log("p.getName(): " + p.getName());
console.log(p);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p));
```

First, I expected the code inside the constructor `Personne(inName)` to be executed while using the operator `new`.

Apparently, this is not the case. Below, I give the output from the execution.

```
$ node loop-closure.js 
p.getName(): toto
{ prototype: { name: false, setName: [Function], getName: [Function] } }
{ name: 'toto', setName: [Function], getName: [Function] }
```

You can see that the constructor is not executed...

However, if I execute the same code on Chrome or Firefox, then the constructor is executed!

FireFox:

```
"go!"
"Given: Tom"
"p.getName(): Tom"
Object { name: "Tom" }
Object { name: "toto", setName: window.onload/PersonnePrototype.setName(inName), getName: window.onload/PersonnePrototype.getName() }
```

Chrome:

```
go!
Given: Tom
p.getName(): Tom
Personne {name: "Tom", setName: function, getName: function}
Object {name: "toto", setName: function, getName: function}
```

I thought that NodeJS is the JavaScript interpreter used by Chrome. If this is correct, then why does the interpretation differs between Chrome and NodeJS?

**UPDATE**

I saw the comments, and I try that:

I just copy/paste the code into a file and call NodeJs on that file.

Yes, you are right: it works as expected.

Then I found what was causing the problem.

I had extra code in the file I executed. I had put a return statement just after the piece of code I gave you. Below, I give you the complete code:

I am using NodeJs version 0.10.35:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.35
```

```js
// We declare the constructor.
function Personne(inName) {
    console.log("go!");
    if ('undefined' != typeof inName) {
        this.name = inName;
    }
}

// We declare the object's prototype (that will be used by the constructor).
var PersonnePrototype = {
    name: 'toto',
    setName: function(inName) {
        this.name = inName; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
    },
    getName: function() {
        return this.name; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
    }
};

Personne.prototype = PersonnePrototype;

var p = new Personne("Tom"); 
console.log("p.getName(): " + p.getName());
console.log(p);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p));



return;

console.log("Does the prototype has a constructor property ? " + Object.getPrototypeOf(p).hasOwnProperty('constructor'));

// Other way to say the same thing:

function Personne() {
    this.prototype = {
        name: false,
        setName: function(inName) {
            this.name = inName; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
        },
        getName: function() {
            return this.name; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
        }
    }
};

var p = new Personne(); // Object "p" has a parent. This parent has been created by the prototype (which is a function).
p.setName("Tom");
console.log("The name is " + p.getName() + " / " + this.name);
console.log("Does the prototype has a constructor property ? " + Object.getPrototypeOf(p).hasOwnProperty('constructor'));

// Ou encore :

var p = Object.create(Personne.prototype);
p.setName("Tom");
console.log("The name is " + p.getName() + " / " + this.name);

// We can see the difference between the prototype and the instanced object.
// Both are objects.
// However, as you can see, they do not present the same properties.

utils.dump(Object.getPrototypeOf(p));
Object.getPrototypeOf(p).name;
utils.dump(p);

if (Object.getPrototypeOf(p).getName() != p.getName()) {
    console.log("The prototype and the object have different properties.");
    console.log("Prototype: " + Object.getPrototypeOf(p).getName());
    console.log("Object: " + p.getName());
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Heritage
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Personne() {
    this.prototype = {
        name: false,
        setName: function(inName) {
            this.name = inName; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
        },
        getName: function() {
            return this.name; // "this" refers to the new object being created.
        }
    }
};

function student() {
    Personne.call(this);
}
```

I though that the code after the return statement did not interfere. Apparently, it does.

NodeJs compiles all the code before it executes it. Therefore, if I redefine the constructor later in the code, then it will modify the first occurrence of it.

OK, but:

```js
var v = 1;
console.log("v = " + v);

var v = 2;
console.log("v = " + v);
```

Output:

```
$ node test1.js 
v = 1
v = 2
```

And:

```js
var v = 1;
console.log("v = " + v);
return;
var v = 2;
console.log("v = " + v);
```

Outputs:

```
$ node test1.js 
v = 1
```

And (may be there is something with references):

```js
var v = { a: 1 };
console.log("v.a = " + v.a);
return;
var v = { a: 2 };
console.log("v.a = " + v.a);
```

Outputs:

```
$ node test1.js 
v.a = 1
```

Nothing unusual here... The code after the return statement does not seem to alter the code before the return statement.

@Alexey Ten

Thanks for the hint.

**Test1.js**:

```js
function Construct() { this.name = "Tom"; }
var v = new Construct();
console.log("v.name = " + v.name);
return;
function Construct() { this.name = "Joe"; }
```

**Test2.js**:

```js
var Construct = function() { this.name = "Tom"; }
var v = new Construct();
console.log("v.name = " + v.name);
return;
var Construct = function() { this.name = "Joe"; }
```

Result for Test1 is: v.name = Joe

Result for Test1 is: v.name = Tom

Comment: Sorry, it is a copy/past mistake: I forgot to say hello ! The edit function does not seem to work.

Comment: I just did a quick spike using your code and the constructor was called. Literally copied your code into a file and ran it:`go!
p.getName(): Tom
{ name: 'Tom' }
{ name: 'toto', setName: [Function], getName: [Function] }`

Comment: Are you sure you run the same code? This is so basic it couldn't work wrong.

Comment: I copied it it from his post, pasted unmodified into `test.js` and then ran `node test.js` with the results posted above.

Comment: @DenisBeurive what node version are you running? I'm on 10.30

Comment: I just copied the code snippet as-is and it showed the expected output, unlike the output you show. I test on node v0.10.31.

Comment: I too copy/pasted your code and ran it. Got exactly the output I expected against Node v0.10.26 and v0.11.12.

Comment: tested in v0.10.33: `go!
p.getName(): Tom
{ name: 'Tom' }
{ name: 'toto', setName: [Function], getName: [Function] }`

Comment: Read about javascript hoisting. It will explain why code after `return` still matters.

Comment: Do you still have a question? I'm no longer sure what you're asking. Perhaps you should overhaul the question to contain only code and explanation that is relevant to whatever question you're currently asking. Using a separate "original" and "edit" sections makes the question very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Hoisting: I think that I have understood. However, I need to validate it by making some testing. I'll make some more tests to make sure I get it right, then I'll write an answer.

Comment: Um, that top-level `return` should be a syntax error imho…

Answer (score 0):

This post was, in fact, not about NodeJs, but about hoisting (thanks  Alexey Ten)

Good explanation:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Having used languages such as C, C++, Java, PHP, Perl, Tcl, Python or GO, I expected JavaScript to behave the same way, regarding variable declaration. If a variable is not declared before it is used, then, depending upon the language:

- You end up with an error.
- The variable's value is undefined.

In JavaScript the result depends on how the variable is declared. Please note that the way a variable is declared determines its scope. Hoisting means that JavaScript will put all variables' declarations at the beginning if the variable's scope.

```js
var x;  // Declaration
x = 10; // Initialization: this is the first time a value is affected to the variable.  
x = 20; // Affectation.
```

In other words:

```js
(function() {
    console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => x = undefined f = undefined
    // Declaration + initialization
    var x = 1; 
    var f = function() {};
})();
```

Is equivalent to:

```js
(function() {
    // Declaration
    var x, f;
    console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => x = undefined f = undefined
    // initialization
    x = 2;
    f = function() {};
})();
```

And this is NOT equivalent to:

```
(function() {
    try {
        console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f);
        // initialization
        x = 2;
        f = function() {};
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message); // => ERROR: x is not defined (and f is not defined either).
    }
})();
```

However, watch out! There are some subtle catches:

```js
(function() {
    try {
        console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f);
        x = 1;
        f = function() {};
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message); // => ERROR: x is not defined (and f is not defined either).
    }
})();

// x and f should be defined ???
console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => ReferenceError: x is not defined.
```

Should x and f be defined? In fact, the code that defines x and f is not executed because en exception is raised just before. If you try this :

```js
(function() { 
    try {
        x = 1;
        f = function() {};
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    }
})();

console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => x = 1 f = function () {}
```

OR:

```js
(function() {
    try {
        console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => x = undefined f = undefined
        x = 1;
        f = function() {};
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    }
})();

console.log("x = " + x + " f = " + f); // => x = 1 f = function () {}
var x = 10, f;
```